# Mouse is stuck in drag mode (hand icon). Cannot click anything other than the top bar. Restarting doesnt fix it!

Tags: 16.04, gnome, mouse, users, gnome-tweak-tool

My main account has an issue that it is constantly stuck in the drag mode (hand icon). Whenever I click anything other than the top menu it produces a hand icon and starts to drag it. I can even now click Conky widgets and drag them around the screen which I couldn't do before.

I was using the tweak tool at the time but I don't think I changed anything that would do this.

I have tried to restart the PC but it persists. However, the guest account works just fine. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

UPDATE: I have found the cause of the issue. It can be reproduced in the Guest account by opening tweak tool and going to "Windows" -> "Window Action Key" and setting the value to "Disabled". Is there any way I can set this value back to "Alt" by using the terminal and fixing my main account?

Answer (score 14):

In my case I knew which program had caused the mouse cursor to 'freeze up'. I was using Archive Manager to drag and drop an image out of a zip file when I got the hand icon. Tried the other answers here without luck.

What worked for me was **Alt-Tabbing** to activate the application then press **Alt-F4** to close the program window. Once the window closed, my mouse cursor returned to normal.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this myself by changing the setting in the terminal.

Open a new terminal with CTRL + Alt + T and enter:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "'<Alt>'"
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy running

```
pkill nautilus
```

Unfroze the mouse icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In tweak tool I somehow managed to reach Windows through Keyboard Tab and the changed the Windows Action Key to Alt. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while dragging and dropping files from Archive Manager for me alt+tab was working but when I tried the below none of them worked:
alt+f4
alt+q

The following commands have worked for me is:
pidof file-roller
kill -9 ID_FROM_LAST_STEP

-9 is for killing the process immediately

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the action/Windows that is being activated by itselft somehow, by software or hardware malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

On Lubuntu (LXQt), killing `lxqt-panel` can sometimes fix this problem.

```bash
pkill lxqt-panel
```